# WPF DataTrigger Works for Image but not for Path

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatrigger

The following dims the image when I disable the button and show clearly when enabled:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UIElement}, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="False">
      <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.25"></Setter>
    </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
...
<Button Name="btnPageFirst" IsEnabled="False">
    <Image Source="..\Resources\imgMoveFirst.png" />
</Button>
```

I want to do a similar effect but with Path. I want to gray the image. But it does not gray and there is no error.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UIElement}, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Gray"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
...
<Button Name="btnPageFirst" IsEnabled="False">
    <Path Data="F1M820.557,535.025L838.189,535.024 817.857,555.36 857.82,555.36 857.82,568.301 817.998,568.301 838.226,588.531 820.557,588.499 793.82,561.765 820.557,535.025z" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="DodgerBlue" Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
</Button>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a [precedence order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx#listing) which is used to calculate the values of the dependency properties during runtime.

The oversimplified precedence list:

1. Local value (what you set on the control)
2. Triggers
3. Style setters

Your problem is that you set `Fill="DodgerBlue"` on your path and because it has higher precedence then the Trigger that is way you don't see the fill change. Also that is why it works for your `Image` because there you don't set the Opacity directly.

To make it work:

1. Remove the `Fill="DodgerBlue"` from your path
2. Set it in your style:

   ```
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
       <Style.Setters>
           <Setter Property="Fill" Value="DodgerBlue"/>
       </Style.Setters>
       <Style.Triggers>
          <!-- ... -->
       </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
   ```

As a side note: if you always "inside" in a button you can rewrite the `RelativeSource` to:

```
RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}
```

Comment: Thank-you for the ideas... however, they did not work. I have tried many variations but it does not work. It seems as if the DataTrigger does not like Path or cannot find the Button... I'm not sure which it is.
The reason I originally set the color directly was so that each Path had it's own color and the global DataTrigger could toggle to Gray when the button was disabled.  Guess my thinking was wrong. I tried Opacity in the DataTrigger without setting it on the Path and it too didn't not work.

Comment: Can you extend your sample? Because the exact code what you've posted with my modifications works in my repro. In an empty project try out my solution then start to break down your code maybe find out the difference or what is causing the problem.

Comment: If there is a problem with `DataTrigger`'s `Binding` there should be an error in the Visual Studio's Output window during runtime.

Comment: Was able to solve my problem by moving the trigger into a baseStyle making it easier to change.
Problem was the trigger never fired when the Path styles were in a resource file and the trigger was in the style of an ancestor control.